# Recording from Behringer X32 into Reaper captures only inputs, not channel outputs

Tags: reaper, behringer, console

I'm currently tasked with recording our school's musicals using a Behringer X32 digital mixer and Reaper as my recording software. However, I've encountered an issue where the recordings only capture the individual inputs from the X32, rather than the final mixed output with all EQ and effects applied. I have to cue in people, and cue them out also (Muting them), so I want to apply that to the recording, so postmixing isn't as much work.

Here's my setup:

Behringer X32 connected to my computer via USB, functioning as the audio interface.
Reaper configured to record audio from the X32, with inputs set to correspond to the USB channels.
Despite setting up Reaper to record from the X32, it seems to be capturing only the individual microphone and instrument inputs, rather than the final mixed output that includes all EQ and effects applied on the X32.

Additionally, I've noticed that muted channels on the X32 are still being recorded, which is not desirable.

I'd like to know how I can configure my setup to properly record the main mix output from the X32, ensuring that all EQ and effects are captured, and that only active channels are recorded while muted channels are excluded.

Any insights or guidance on configuring the routing and settings on both the X32 and Reaper would be greatly appreciated. I would *love* for someone to help me soon as this is urgent, and our Musical is in 3 days! Thank you in advance for your help!

Here are some images of my setup:

[Images](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1-3a398Aq4zL3IP9ude2AouRfdbex4R0b?usp=drive_link)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the X32:

1. Press the Routing button
2. Go to the Card Out tab
3. Select the channels you want to record. If you want to record the outputs, scroll down and you'll find Out 1-8 and Out 9-16.

[image: Card out menu]

If you want to record the inputs after processing, you can do that too:

Comment: Ok, that is a really helpful solution, and thanks for your time, but I will also be recording using a matrix, and to output XLR, so I will be using the output 1-16 for something else. Tonight was night one, and it went well, and I tested recording using Reaper (The inputs), and it might be fine. Tonight our camera crew will be recording our show, with the matrix recording (And the backup 32 Channel USB Audio Interface).

Answer (score 2):

You are using direct outputs for each channel which sends the signal to the DAW before the EQ or any other processing. If you want to record a live performance, rather than multitrack recording from direct out, then you need to change the USB routing from direct out to a mix bus channel (e.g. LR or mix bus 1)

Comment: And how would he do that @Timinycricket?